# My images doesn´t appear in my ecommerce using Django

Tags: python, django

When i run my code with the local server my images are not visualized, there are images icons but not the  image itself.

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

my template tienda.py:

```
{% extends 'tienda/index.html'%}

{%load static%}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
        {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" >
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h6><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h6>
                <hr>

                <button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn  update-cart">Agregar al carrito</button>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="">Ver</a>
                <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right;"><strong>${{product.price|floatformat:2}}</strong></h4>
            </div>

        </div>

        

        {%endfor%}
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

my model Product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank = False)
    images = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: try to add this line in your html file {% static "< your image folder name in static folder > as baseurl" %}

Comment: Where are the Product image files originating from?  i.e are you uploading an image file into `Product.images` through a Form submission?     Or are these static images you have in a folder somewhere (like `static/images`)?

Comment: @Foot these images are in a folder named (static/images) im not uploading them no anywhere, just adding them from the admin pannel. And when i click on the image URL i can see them in another tab, but not in my view where all the products are.